# Why I got -Graphics- when i use "Plot"?

Tags: plotting

[image]

Recently, when i use "Plot" in mathematica 9.0, the result is -Graphics- not a picture. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: I think you are in Kernel mode, not in the Front End.

Comment: Have you tried restarting? What OS are you using? Is this in a notebook?

Comment: Execute ``<<Version6`Graphics` `` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to know without more information about your system and what you did.
Here is one mildly contrived way to produce the result you describe:

```
<< Version5`Graphics`
$DisplayFunction = ToString;
```

[image]

If that is indeed in code you ran you can, as J.M. comments above, restore this with:

```
<< Version6`Graphics`
$DisplayFunction = Identity;
```

Comment: Guess who is J.M.?

Comment: @belisarius I don't feel like having to edit every reference when he updates his name.  Sorry if it's confusing but frankly "Guess who it is" is confusing anyway IMHO.

Comment: I promise to change my name back when my Gedanken *Mathematica* license expires and I can use the usual version regularly again. :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't asking for you to modify your answer. My half-pun was intended for helping the OP to identify the comment you was referring to.

Comment: @Guess I think we all await that day eagerly.  Your *Gedanken* clearly works better than mine, by the way.